# MYSQL: ordenar por rows específicas dentro do SELECT

Tags: mysql, select, order-by

To tentando resolver isso há uns tres dias e não achei a resposta em nenhum lugar

Eu tenho uma tabela no banco de dados onde preciso fazer um SELECT em todos os produtos mas eles precisam ser ordenados conforme a média entre data X e data X, um exemplo basico da tabela q fiz rapidamente

[image: Exemplo da formação da tabela]

Os SELECTS e GROUPS estão funcionando, é só o ORDER que nao consigo resolver, uma das varias queries que tentei sem sucesso pra organizar as rows:

```
SELECT product, time, date FROM graficos
ORDER BY time HAVING (date BETWEEN 2017-02-20 AND 2017-02-23) DESC
```

Exemplo bem resumido em mais detalhes (a tabela original é gigante demais pra colar aqui):

```
-------------------------------
 PRODUCT  | TIME |    DATE    |


Bombom    |  35  | 2017-02-15 |
Gato      |  25  | 2017-02-20 |
Pizza     |  28  | 2017-02-23 |
-------------------------------
```

Saída:

```
-------------------------------
Pizza     |  28  | 2017-02-23 |
Gato      |  25  | 2017-02-20 |
Bombom    |   0  | 2017-02-15 |
-------------------------------
```

Comment: Exemplifique com registros da tabela. Quais são os registros e como você  precisa na saída?

Comment: acabei de dar um update com os detalhes q vc pediu Murillo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um `BETWEEN` no comando de ordenação sem problemas.

Um exemplo simplificado de como poderia fazer:

```
SELECT
*
FROM graficos
ORDER BY (
  IF(`date` BETWEEN '2017-02-20' AND '2017-02-23', 1, 50)
)
```

Note que estou fazendo o `IF` e colocando os valores 1 e 50.
Você pode colocar qualquer valor que quiser ali, eu utilizei estes apenas para ilustrar. O que você precisa entender neste ponto, é que o resultado desta expressão será utilizado para fazer a ordenação dos registros.

Answer (score 0):

No MySQL tudo é ou vira tabela.

Uma coisa que você pode fazer é pegar as linhas do jeito que estão vindo, como uma tabela, e ordenar essa tabela que veio.

EX:

```
SELECT PRODUCT,TIME,DATE  FROM ( SEU_SQL_QUE_FUNCIONA_MAS_NAO_ESTA_ORDENADO ) AS tabelatemp ORDER BY TIME DESC
```